# Unable to execute RSeval() in remotely connected client in R

Tags: r, rserve

I was executing `RSeval(c,"4+5");` and encountered :

> Error in RSeval(c,"4+5") : remote evaluation failed

in a remote machine connected to a linux server which is running daemon Rserve, where c is connection object. The connection was successful though.

Please share your insights.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That could be many things, e.g. if Rserve requires authentication. If that's the case, you can use RS.connect and RS.login from the more modern implementation of RSclient (see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSclient/RSclient.pdf).